# "bower install breeze" for MEAN stack

Tags: breeze, mean-stack

I am developing a sample app using MEAN stack and tried to install BreezeJS via bower. But it downloads whole bunch of .NET related stuff. I read from the BreezeJS documentation, that it can be used in Non-MS backends.
Any hints on how can I use bower to install breezeJS or do I have to download files manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update 26 May 2014

There is now an **official breezejs bower package** for *client* assets. Install from a terminal/command window with

`bower install breezejs`

> Case matters! Be sure to spell "breezejs" in all lowercase.

This package contains the core JavaScript distribution files PLUS

- adapters - the officially supported breeze adapters in the core, including the mongo client adapter
- labs - the currently "approved" breeze.labs

HTH

p.s.: You still use nmp to install the *breeze-mongodb* module on your *node server*.

### Original

Feel your pain. It's helpful to our priority setting to know that this matters to you.

We are in the midst of doing two things about this.

1. refactoring the github repository into multiple repos to be more sensitive to technology preferences.
2. working with the current keepers of the Breeze bower repos to refactor accordingly; actually, they have offered to let us take over ... and we will; we just need a little more time.

Until then, I'm afraid you'll have to grab the JavaScript files from github yourself. Fortunately there are not many of them.

Breeze client JavaScript files are in the [build folder of the breeze.js repo](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/tree/master/build).

Breeze Labs for JS clients are in the [breeze.js.labs repo](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs).

The *breeze-mongodb* module for your node server you can install with npm.